# DialogBox Display in Android Application : How to set Context out of Activity

Tags: android, notifications, android-alertdialog, android-context

I am creating a backup app in `android` using `BackupManager`but as backup actually occur at schedule time not promptly, I just want to know how can I show a message in `dialogbox` that `onBackup()`is get called and now your data is saved on google servers. The main problem is what the context of dialogbox should be??
so far I have tried this but when `onBackup()`was called it didnot display

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTitle("BACKUP ALERT");
    builder.setMessage("Your Backup has been processed");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
```

I wrote this in `onBackup()`method but it didnot display on my application. I want to show this message whenever backup occur and user opens my application or if he has already opened I want to display it no matter which activity is foreground that time or can someone give me the idea how to make it a `notification` in android `notification` bar.

There is an error on `Logcat` at the line where I created and showed the dialog..

```
12-28 13:22:52.722: E/JavaBinder(16540): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
12-28 13:22:52.722: E/JavaBinder(16540): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
12-28 13:22:52.722: E/JavaBinder(16540):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
12-28 13:22:52.722: E/JavaBinder(16540):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:107)
12-28 13:22:52.722: E/JavaBinder(16540):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:118)
12-28 13:22:52.722: E/JavaBinder(16540):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:971)
12-28 13:22:52.722: E/JavaBinder(16540):    at com.vahzay.android.smstrove.MySmsBackupAgent1.onBackup(MySmsBackupAgent1.java:233)
12-28 13:22:52.722: E/JavaBinder(16540):    at android.app.backup.BackupAgent$BackupServiceBinder.doBackup(BackupAgent.java:490)
12-28 13:22:52.722: E/JavaBinder(16540):    at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:80)
12-28 13:22:52.722: E/JavaBinder(16540):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
12-28 13:22:52.722: E/JavaBinder(16540):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

and my code for the dialogbox is:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setMessage("Backup Alert")
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {                   
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
        {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your SMS Record that you requested to backup earlier is now processed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //-->233
        }
    }).create().show();
}
```

Comment: is your problem solved with my given solution?

Comment: you are using alert Dialog in tabhost ?

Comment: @PratikSharma no my problem didnot solve..just posted the logcat error...
@MehulRanpara I dont know what a tabhost is..I am just running `bmgr`android tool to call `onBackup()` immediately and as soon as it reached the `.create().show()` line it caught errors,above this everything is working fine..

Comment: @aneelasafdar :`Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` line means you are trying to show alert from bg thread. solution is use `runOnUiThread` for showing alert from bg thread

Comment: @aneelasafdar you can use `Handler Runnable` to call such `UI component` from the `non-UI thread`.

Comment: can you people show some code example of how to do it..Thanks

Comment: @aneelasafdar : take [this](http://pastebin.com/NdnKK76S) example for how we show alert using runOnUiThread

Comment: @aneelasafdar : solved or not?

Comment: can you me another link as it is not working here..

Comment: @aneelasafdar : it's better if you send me  link for code then i will see why it's not working because this is proper way to use runOnUiThread

Comment: I meant to say that link you sent me is not opening here as this website access is restricted on my network and thanks for your time

Comment: [https://gist.github.com/] here is the link

Comment: I am solving some other issues for the time being..That problem is still pending..As soon as I start that issue again and feel any problem,I would prefer to contact you and again thanks for beings so considerate.. :)

Comment: @aneelasafdar : this is great idea,if you have no issue then i can solve this issue for you and when you complete your other work then integrate it in your latest code. what you think about this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

With,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
```

**EDIT :**

Another Option is **Static Context from Application Class**,

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

Now call from anywhere,

`MyApplication.getAppContext()` to get your application context statically.

Thanks.

Comment: tried it but same result..No dialog appeared while Log is showing the `onBackup()`call..

Comment: @aneelasafdar see the edited solution for your problem. THat will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, if it worked.
I have observed that we need to use both `.create()` and `.show()` to show an `alertDialiog`.

So try to use `builder.create().show();`

**Edit-** I have the follwoing working code for me,

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setMessage("Network is in Roaming")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {                   
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
            {

            }
        }).create().show();
```

If at all it doesn't works, then you can call an activity and show the same dialog here in the activty. You can make the activity as transparent, so that only dialog is visible.

Comment: i think this question need more explanation or some relevant part of code

Comment: @aneelasafdar : You can try my edited code, if it works. if not then as @ prosper said, this is the time to post some more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

try this way might be help

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(youractivity.this);
```

ok let try in that way

- create one static Context mContext;
- then in your activity onCreate write like mContext = youractivity.this;
- that's it just simple call static variable like mContext;

Comment: onBackup() isn't a method in an Activity.

Comment: yes its in a `BackupAgent`extended class,problem is that I am not sure about the context..

Comment: Also, making the context static is a brilliant way to create memory leaks.

Comment: @aneelasafdar : but way you are not using BackupAgent constructor for sending Context to show AlertDialog ?

Comment: I was using `getApplicationContext()` as context for `AlertDialog`..there is a `onCreate()` method, sorry for the previous blunder.

Comment: @aneelasafdar :  see @ Sahil Mahajan Mj answer i think this help you more